# When an athlete gets drafted but college degrees aren't finished, what do they do?

Tags: basketball

Say for example an NBA player gets drafted at the end of his sophomore year and his two years away from receiving his bachelors degree, how does he finish his bachelor's? Does he go to school during his NBA career? Does he go online? Does he go during the summer?

Alternatively, if declare for the draft and go undrafted, can they come back to finish their degrees?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer for players that are drafted and have reasonable success as a professional athlete is that they don't finish their degrees, at least not on any "normal" timescale. For instance, Steph Curry left Davidson in 2009, [but didn't graduate until 2022](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/09/01/sport/steph-curry-davidson-graduation-nba-spt-intl/index.html). This is understandable as the *minimum* salary in the NBA is just over $1 million per year.

If a player is undrafted (or even if they're drafted and decide for some other reason not to take up professional basketball), they can complete their degree - although if they actually got as far as the draft rather than [withdrawing soon after the NBA Draft Combine](https://www.hoopsrumors.com/2022/05/ncaas-withdrawal-deadline-looms-for-drafts-early-entrants.html) they would no longer be eligible to play college sport.